# Autofac's `reloadOnChange` doesn't reload the configuration?

Tags: c#, autofac

I have a simple basic configuration for Autofac , which uses JSON configuration file :

```
 var config = new ConfigurationBuilder();
 config.AddJsonFile("autofac.json",false,true); //notice reloadOnChange

 // Register the ConfigurationModule with Autofac.
    var module = new ConfigurationModule(config.Build());
    var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
    builder.RegisterModule(module);


 // Set the dependency resolver to be Autofac.
    _container = builder.Build();
```

Here is the JSON  :

```
{
  "defaultAssembly": "AutoFacConfigFile",
  "components": [
    {
      "type": "AutoFacConfigFile.ConsoleOutput",
      "services": [
        {
          "type": "AutoFacConfigFile.IOutput"
        }
      ],
      "instanceScope": "single-instance",
      "injectProperties": true
    }
  ]
}
```

The `ConsoleOutput` writes the exact input string :

```
public class ConsoleOutput : IOutput
    {
        public void Write(string content)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(content);
        }
    }
```

However , The `ConsoleOutput2` writes the exact input string  + "222222222":

```
public class ConsoleOutput2 : IOutput
    {
        public void Write(string content)
        {
             Console.WriteLine(content+"22222222222");
        }
    }
```

I want to see that if I change form `ConsoleOutput` to `ConsoleOutput2`, then I'll see the different output on runtime, that's why I created a loop :

```
  static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            AutofacExt.InitAutofac();
            var writer = AutofacExt.GetFromFac<IOutput>();
            Get(writer).Wait();

        }

        public static async Task Get(IOutput writer)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            {
               await Task.Delay(1000);
               writer.Write("s");
            }
        }
```

However, even if I change the JSON file, when the loop is running, I don't see a new response. I only see the old response :

[image]

**Question:**

Why does changing from `ConsoleOutput` to `ConsoleOutput2` doesn't reflects the change?

I expect:

```
"s"
"s"
"s"
                             -- file changed and saved here --
"s2222222222"
"s2222222222"
"s2222222222"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Autofac doesn't provide or own the configuration builder. It's not "Autofac's `reloadOnChange`", it's "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration's `reloadOnChange`."

Autofac will read configuration provided in that format, however, once the container is built, that's it. There is no "tie" or anything between the container contents and the configuration after that.

Containers are effectively immutable. [Updating the container is being removed for a variety of reasons](https://github.com/autofac/Autofac/issues/811) and it's these same reasons the container isn't rebuilt on configuration change.

If you need to change the contents on configuration change, you'll need to do that in your application code.

- Catch the event that indicates change
- Build an all new container
- Swap the new container out for the old container

That's easier said than done, especially as the app is running and things may be holding references to objects resolved from the old container. That's actually a big reason this isn't supported. I have no guidance in how to accomplish that and would actively argue against it.

Again, [check out this discussion if you're interested in more on why containers are immutable.](https://github.com/autofac/Autofac/issues/811)

Comment: Thanks, Reagarding "_would actively argue against it_" -  What if today I'm using `EmailSender` and I tomorrow I want to change it to  `SmsSender` (without compile)   ? how would you do that  ?  the only thing that I can think of is to read it to a redis , and to inspect that value with `if` in code. but that will break the `Injection` phylosophy. Becuase I want that today `ILogger` will be `EmailSender` and tomorrow to be `SmsSender`....(without recompile) ...

Comment: Restarting the app is an option. Other options are in that thread I linked to twice. It's long, but it's got everything I have to say about the issue.